# Make http.request in Node.js work for browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, http, cross-browser

I want to write a single codebase plugin that works with both `Node.js` and `browser`. I am writing the base code in Node.js and then converting it to have support for browser version using the node module `browserify`. All my `GET` and `POST` requests works fine when I execute the code in `Node.js`. If I write the `ajax` request, its works fine for browser. I am using `http` node module for making request to remote server. How can I make the remote server request work in browser version without writing any separate `ajax` request? The main idea is to keep the same codebase and get it to work in both ways.
I have the following sample code written in Node.js

```
var http = require('http');

function Test() {
    var self = this;
}

Test.prototype.get_data = function() {
    var fetch = http.request("http://stackoverflow.com/", function(res) {
        var result = ""
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            result += chunk;
        });
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log("response.................");
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
    fetch.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("error..........");
        console.log(e);
    });
    fetch.end();
    return 'hello world'
};

API = new Test();

module.exports = API;
```

Now when I execute the code in `Node.js` by calling `API.get_data()`, it works fine for me. But after I convert the code using `browserify` and then call from the `HTML` file by `API.get_data()` I get the following error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://stackoverflow.com/. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` when I run in chrome. Any idea how to make the same `Node.js` codebase work without writing `jsonp ajax` for browser.
Mentioned below is the header when I run in Mozilla.

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control   public, max-age=21
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  36325
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 27 May 2014 20:03:47 GMT
Expires Tue, 27 May 2014 20:04:10 GMT
Last-Modified   Tue, 27 May 2014 20:03:10 GMT
Vary    *
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  __qca=P0-1262336656-1387719953106; __utma=140029553.331521903.1387719953.1389033371.1389035323.13; __utmz=140029553.1389035323.13.13.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); prov=3d930d0c-1785-4421-b319-33036243183e; _ga=GA1.2.331521903.1387719953
Host    stackoverflow.com
Origin  http://127.0.0.1
Referer http://127.0.0.1/index.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0

2 requests

51.2 KB
```

Answer (score 3):

`browserify` already has the [http module for the browser](https://github.com/substack/http-browserify), but you don't need to do anything special to get it. It's what's automatically used in the browser when you browserify a script that uses `require('http')`

Try this for the CORS error problem:

```
var fetch = http.request({
  host: "stackoverflow.com",
  port: 80,
  path: "/",
  method: "GET",
  withCredentials: false // this is the important part
}, function(res) {
    var result = ""
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        result += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log("response.................");
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: I installed node module `http-browserify` also just to make sure am not missing anything but still I am getting cross domain error while making the request. However, I am sure if I need to use the below code
`var bundle = browserify({
    require : { http : 'http-browserify' }
});`

Comment: You should supply as much detail as possible (in your original question) if you're getting an error (e.g. error text, headers sent and received, etc).

Comment: Updated the sample code what I am trying to achieve. Hope this will help you to understand and provide me a better suggestion for the approach.

Comment: I am not sure what is missing but still getting the same error even after adding `withCredentials: false` and making the changes as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t access that kind of url location from local host on chrome, it’s flagged as a CORS security risk. A couple things you can try are 1. Upload the pages to a hosted domain and then you can try from www.yourdomain.com instead of local host. Try use https in the request instead of http.